# Hungarian Notations/Systems Hungarian Should I?

Tags: coding-standards, notation

I was wondering would it be worth using a form of standard such as Hungarian Notation/Systems Hungarian?

Why would I bother if everything I'm doing now is working fine?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to remove the irrelevant parts?  It seems you're just asking one thing, and the first three paragraphs are irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struggling not to use Hungarian notation](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/65065/struggling-not-to-use-hungarian-notation)

Comment: @S.Lott I don't think it is entirely irrelevant (Maybe the "I'm using Git" part is) but obviously if he was on a big team we would tell him to consult his team and not just do whatever he wishes.

Comment: Surprised this hasn't been posted:  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: do you like kludge ? I prefer lean code, but if you need the reminder... just don't expect me to work on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have seen the atrocities people commit in the name of hungarian notation. Please don't go there. Today's IDE/Intellisense etc. are more than capable of telling you about the variable type etc.

And then there is the whole issue of untyped languages.

Answer (score 10):

No, it is not worth using **any** form of Hungarian Notation.

Eric Evans in [Domain Driven Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321125215) (also available as a mini-book on [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly)) does an excellent job highlighting the essence of a ubiquitious language:

> To create a supple, knowledge-rich
>   design calls for a versatile, shared
>   team language ...
>
> Use the model as the backbone of a
>   language. Commit the team to
>   exercising that language relentlessly
>   in all communication within the team
>   and in the code. Use the same language
>   in diagrams, writing, and especially
>   speech.

The terminology of the day-to-day discussions with the domain experts should not be disconnected from the terminology embedded in the code.

And considering that the code is the most important product of a software project, it is essential that there be little room for anything that doesn't convey the the domain experts concepts and ideas.

In that world, a world where our code reflects the domain, Hungarian notation has absolutely no reason for being.

Comment: The only thing I do is to add a prefix to member variables (m or _) in order to differentiate them from local varables.

Answer (score 3):

Well if it is what you prefer, and it makes your code easier to read and understand, then it is a great idea to do. There is of course your typical holy war of not using Systems Hungarian, but if it makes you a more productive code, I say f*ck 'em.

I do however say consider using [Apps Hungarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_vs._Apps_Hungarian) as it is a little more useful in identifying the purpose of a variable (which is what the intention of Hungarian notation was).

The answer here really depends on the language and way you code. For instance, a PHP programmer who makes use of the dynamic typing would not want to use Systems for the fact that the variable wouldn't be correctly pinned down by a type. In this situation I again make my claim towards Apps Hungarian.

Comment: I agree with your point, but I think that just a more descriptive name such as $lastname would obviously mean a string not an integer or anything...

Comment: @MattyD The variable could be a pointer to a char array. Doesn't really tell you that now does it?

Comment: You sunk my battle ship... I'm mainly a web developer over a software developer so I have never really had to deal with pointers etc...

Comment: @MattyD I knew I smelled PHP.. but honestly the answer to this question is a bit dependent on his coding style and what language he is using. I mean if he is using PHP and types just don't matter then neither does using Systems Hungarian (Although Apps is another story)

Comment: not really. Depending on the language, there is always a standard way of storing strings, be it char array or string class, or whatever. If you intend to point out how a developer can do something that is not standard, keep in mind that he can do the same with notation.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer something opposite of the question. Hungarian notation actually works GREAT with autocomplete.

Say you have a variable, and the name is intHeightOfMonster.

Say you forget the name of the variable

It could be heightOfMonster or MonsterHeight or MeasurementMonsterHeight

You want to be able to type a letter and get the autocomplete suggest to you some variable names.

Knowing that the heightOfMonster is an int, you just type i and voila.

Save time.

Comment: This actually depend from the ide. In VS typing height will show you the possible variables. Anyway if your ide don't do that, what should I do if i remember the variable name but not it's type?